# Updating a DriveItem with special characters returns error

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to update a drive item's parent reference, where the drive item's name or the new parent path containing special characters (`%25` for example), and both new parent and item are in the same Group and Drive.

- When the new parent's path contains those characters I get an invalid request exception.
- When the update drive item's name contains those character I get an "Item Not Found" exception, but the item is moved to the destination after the `25` was stripped from the item's name.

My code works fine except for these two scenarios.

Here is what i try to do:

```
destinationPath = Uri.EscapeDataString(destinationPath);

var destination = await client
    .Groups[groupId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath(destinationPath)
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

DriveItem newItem = new DriveItem {
    ParentReference = new ItemReference { Id = destination.Id }
};

sourcePath = Uri.EscapeDataString(sourcePath);

var movedItem = await client
    .Groups[groupId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath(sourcePath)
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

var result = await client
    .Groups[groupId]
    .Drives[driveId]
    .Items[movedItem.Id]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(newItem);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneDrive doesn't support `%` (or several other special characters) in file or path names. This isn't related to Microsoft Graph, they aren't supported by OneDrive itself (or many file systems for that matter).

From [Invalid file names and file types in OneDrive, OneDrive for Business, and SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-OneDrive-OneDrive-for-Business-and-SharePoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa):

> Characters that aren't allowed in file and folder names in OneDrive, OneDrive for Business on Office 365, and SharePoint Online: `" * : < > ? / \ |`
>
> Characters that aren't allowed in file and folder names in OneDrive for Business on SharePoint Server 2013: `~ " # % & * : < > ? / \ { | }.`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @marc, then why are names which contains those characters, still allowed in OneDrive/Office365 Groups web interfaces?

Comment: Support for `%` and `#` was recently added to SharePoint. See https://dev.office.com/blogs/upcoming-changes-to-sharepoint-and-onedrive-for-business-apis-to-support-and-in-file-names for details on how this is being handled at the API level.